# GraphicsMagick :: -alpha and -annotate equivalent of ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

ImageMagick convert have -alpha option that :

```
-alpha option        activate, deactivate, reset, or set the alpha channel
```

is there an equivalent option in GraphicsMagick convert?
Similarly, is there an -annotate option?
Thank you!

Comment: There are alternate ways of doing some operations (work-arounds) where the GraphicsMagick command-line is lacking vis-à-vis the ImageMagick command-line. Rather than me describe them all, it would be much easier if you said exactly what effect you wish to achieve.

Comment: In the older ImageMagick and possibly in GraphicsMagick, turning on alpha was -matte and turning off alpha was +matte. I do not know Graphicsmagick, but the alternative to -annotate in ImageMagick is most likely -draw. GraphicsMagick likely has that as it was an early offshoot of ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to convert a transparent PNG to JPG but the result wasn't satisfying (as per attached). I managed to add a white background using the following command line script 
`magick convert image1.png -background white -alpha remove -alpha off image2.jpg`

The nodejs's gm utility code I used to get the same result:

```
gm('PATH/TO/IMAGE')
   .setFormat('jpg')
   .fill('white')
   .opaque('none')
   .write('PATH/TO/OUTPUT', function(err, image) {
          if (err) return cb(err);

          return cb(null, image);
   });
```

[image]